# Apache Ambari maven build fails: "Connect to nexus-private.hortonworks.com:80 [...] timed out"?

Tags: maven, ambari

Attempting to build apache ambari v2.7.3 on CentOS 7 from source via the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.3)

Getting error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy:jar:2.7.3.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-core:pom:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557 from/to apache-hadoop (http://nexus-private.hortonworks.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Connect to nexus-private.hortonworks.com:80 [nexus-private.hortonworks.com/54.173.242.72] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]

Some dedebugging configs:

```sh
[root@HW001 ~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 Downloads]# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# npm --version
3.10.10
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# python --version
Python 2.7.5
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# easy_install --version
setuptools 0.9.8
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# yum list installed | grep rpm-build
rpm-build.x86_64                      4.11.3-40.el7                   @base
rpm-build-libs.x86_64                 4.11.3-40.el7                   @base
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# node --version
v6.17.1
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]#
[root@HW001 ~]# npm list -g | grep brunch
├─┬ brunch@2.10.17
│ │ ├── brunch-skeletons@0.1.6
│ ├─┬ serve-brunch@0.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some debugging, it turns out there were 2 problems (#2 may not be a problem for you, will explain):

1) Needed to add another repo. Used a *variation* of the solution found in another [post](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-TW&u=https://www.twblogs.net/a/5d5f397bbd9eee541c328e0c&prev=search).

> The repository configured by Ambari is nexus-private.hortonworks.com, but the address is inaccessible. Solution: Set https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ to the repository address, which contains the required dependencies.

So in the project's `pom.xml` file before building, I add...

```sh
....
  <repositories>
    ....
    <repository>
      <id>Spring Plugins</id>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-hortonworks</id>
      <url>https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

....
```

---

2) In the `pom.xml` snippet above, I also have added another repo that is not normally in there, `Spring Plugins`. This is because I was getting errors for some artifact called `ringer-cors` from the `nexus-hortonworks` repo. Why was maven looking there? It appears that it was due to that fact that I initially had the nexus-hortonworks repo specified in the `$M2_HOME/conf/setting.xml` file as a [mirror](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html#Advanced_Mirror_Specification) for everything other than `central`, eg. `mirrorOf` value was `*,!central` (like the linked to solution for #1 suggests).

> Could not find artifact ring-cors:ring-cors:jar:0.1.5 in nexus-hortonworks

I **assume** that there was some problem where maven was checking the mirrors before the repositories in the project pom, not finding `ringer-cors` and giving up OR that there were no suitable repos anywhere in the settings or project pom to get the `ringer-cors` artifact. So I got info from the [maven repo site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ring-cors/ring-cors/0.1.5) on what maven repos had `ringer-cors`, took `nexus-hortonworks` out of the settings file and  edited the project `pom.xml` to what is shown above. (if this is a wrong interpretation, please someone with more maven experience let me know).